# TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.readdirSync is not a function (How to read names of files in a directory in typescript?)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, facebook, react-typescript

Is there a way of reading names of files in a directory in typescript?

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

const RetrieveFiles  = (): string[] => {
    const __dirname = './src/data/app-versions'
    const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
   return files;
}
```

I am  trying that but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.readdirSync is not a function
```

The above works in node but not in typescript.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you run this code in typescript?

Comment: Yes, I am running this code in typescript @aleksxor

Comment: I mean, how exactly? ts-node, webpack transpilation (as I can guess by the error text)?

Comment: I created a react web app with typescript and I am running it in the browser. @aleksxor

Comment: Browser does not have `fs` module. It's inner module of `node.js`.

Comment: In fact browsers do not have any inner modules. Only predefined Web APIs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction that's pretty much what you're limited to when you want to work with files in the browser

Comment: Sure, how  How can I read names of files in a directory in typescript(in a  browser)? @aleksxor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233195/discussion-between-byusa-and-aleksxor).